# how can I force SQL to only evaluate a join if the value can be converted to an INT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a query that uses several subqueries. It's about 100 lines, so I'll leave it out. The issue is that I have several rows returned as part of one subquery that need to be joined to an integer value from the main query. Like so:

```
Select 
... columns ... 
from 
... tables ... 
        (
        select 
        ... column ... 
        from 
        ... tables ...  
        INNER JOIN core.Type mt 
                        on m.TypeID = mt.TypeID 
                    where dpt.[DataPointTypeName] = 'TheDataPointType'
                        and m.TypeID in (100008, 100009, 100738, 100739) 
                        and datediff(d, m.MeasureEntered, GETDATE()) <  365 -- only care about measures from past year 
                        and dp.DataPointValue <> ''
                        ) as subMdp                     
         ) as subMeas 
    on (subMeas.DataPointValue NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'  
        and subMeas.DataPointValue = cast(vcert.IDNumber as varchar(50))) -- THIS LINE
... more tables etc ...
```

The issue is that if I take out the `cast(vcert.IDNumber as  varchar(50)))` it will attempt to compare a value like 'daffodil' to a number like 3245. Even though the datapoint that contains 'daffodil' is an orphan record that **should be filtered out by the `INNER JOIN`** 4 lines above it. It works fine if I try to compare a string to a string but blows up if I try to compare a string to an int -- even though I have a clause in there to only look at things that can be converted to integers: `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`. If I specifically filter out the record containing 'daffodil' then it's fine.  If I move the `NOT LIKE` line into the subquery it will still fail. It's like the `NOT LIKE` is evaluated last no matter what I do.

So the real question is why SQL would be evaluating a JOIN clause before evaluating a WHERE clause contained in a subquery. Also how I can force it to only evaluate the JOIN clause if the value being evaluated is convertible to an INT. Also why it would be evaluating a record that will definitely not be present after an INNER JOIN is applied.

I understand that there's a strong element of *query optimizer voodoo* going on here. On the other hand I'm telling it to do an INNER JOIN and the optimizer is specifically ignoring it. I'd like to know why.

Comment: Explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191701/tsql-divide-by-zero-encountered-despite-no-columns-containing-0

Comment: Did you not read my link? Another example with a similar issue and shows you to how to get around it with a `case` expression. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192524/unable-to-cast-value-as-float/7192951#7192951 It isn't anything specifically to do with joins SQL Server will often order operations so the compute scalar happens before the filter.

Comment: @Martin: that did it, I put the NOT LIKE in a case statement in the SELECT in the submeas subquery. I can write it in as an answer but you should get the credit, so write it up and I'll mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is discussed in [this item of feedback](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) on the connect site.

Whilst logically you might expect the filter to exclude any `DataPointValue` values that contain any non numeric characters SQL Server appears to be ordering the `CAST` operation in the execution plan before this filter happens. Hence the error.

Until Denali comes along with its `TRY_CONVERT` function the way around this is to wrap the usage of the column in a case expression that repeats the same logic as the filter.

Comment: Good lord, SQL optimizer voodoo is killing me. I have a straight join after the subquery `(subMeas.DataPointValue = vcert.IDNumber)`and I get results. I then comment out the line `and dp.DataPointValue <> ''` and it errors on the value '00spr' (which is an orphan record that should be filtered by the JOIN *AND* wouldn't have been filtered by the `<> ''` anyway. WTF.

Comment: @jcollum - If you look at the two execution plans you should probably see that the placement of a compute scalar operator changes somewhere.

Comment: @jcollum, I guess it's not totally a problem of the optimizer, but due to ANSI NULLS. Try ISNULL(dp.DataPointValue,'') <> ''

Answer (score 2):

> So the real question is why SQL would be evaluating a JOIN clause
>   before evaluating a WHERE clause contained in a subquery.

Because SQL engines are required to behave as if that's what they do. They're required to act like they build a working table from all of the table constructors in the FROM clause; expressions in the WHERE clause are applied to that working table.

Joe Celko wrote about this many times on Usenet. [Here's an old version](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/browse_thread/thread/23420f2604fe397f/dd00309cefc27077?hl=en&ie=UTF-8) with more details.

Comment: I don't feel this answers my question. There's one sentence in particular that isn't the behavior that I'm seeing: "Start in the FROM clause and build a working table from all of the 
joins, unions, intersections, and whatever other table constructors are there". I'm not seeing that; instead I'm seeing an evaluation of a where clause happening before an INNER JOIN. My question is how I can force the WHERE clause to only be evaluated on the results of the join.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
 NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

isn`t work well. Example:

```
DECLARE @Int nvarchar(20)= ' 454 54'
SELECT  CASE WHEN @INT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Is_Number
Result: 1
```

But it is not a number!

To check if it is real int value , you should use **ISNUMERIC** function. Let`s check this:

```
DECLARE @Int nvarchar(20)= ' 454 54'
SELECT ISNUMERIC(@int) Is_Int
Result:0
```

Result is correct.

So, instead of

```
NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

try to change this to

```
ISNUMERIC(subMeas.DataPointValue)=0
```

**UPDATE**

How check if value is integer?
First [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109574/how-to-get-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-t-sql):

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC(str) AND str NOT LIKE '%.%' AND str NOT LIKE '%e%' AND str NOT LIKE '%-%'
```

Second:

```
CREATE Function dbo.IsInteger(@Value VarChar(18))
Returns Bit
As 
Begin

  Return IsNull(
     (Select Case When CharIndex('.', @Value) > 0 
                  Then Case When Convert(int, ParseName(@Value, 1)) <> 0
                            Then 0
                            Else 1
                            End
                  Else 1
                  End
      Where IsNumeric(@Value + 'e0') = 1), 0)

End
```

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` doesn't guarantee that the value can be cast to an `int` and even if it did as `ISNUMERIC(subMeas.DataPointValue + 'e0')` does this wouldn't fix the OP's issue - Which is essentially the same as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191701/tsql-divide-by-zero-encountered-despite-no-columns-containing-0

Comment: And you seem to be missing the point of the original `'%[^0-9]%'` expression. It has a negation to find non numeric characters so the result from your test is entirely expected. You could equally well have used `fish` instead of `454 54`

Comment: I got the `NOT LIKE` phrase from a blog post that was about ISNUMERIC not working like you expect. ISNUMERIC basically says 'can this be converted to any sort of number'. '454 54' could be converted to a number if you are using spaces for separators. Maybe it isn't very sensible way to display a number but it still work.

Answer (score -1):

Filter out the non-numeric records in a subquery or CTE

Comment: If I move the NOT LIKE clause into the subquery I get the same result. Already tried it.

Comment: That won't work. CTEs and sub queries are inline constructs and the definitions get expanded out by the optimiser.