# Error when summing converted column

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a table in SQL Server that contains 2 columns: `Question_asked`, `Response`

The `Response` column is of the datatype `varchar(500)` and holds the users response to the question that is held in the column `Question_asked`

I have created a view `V_age_attr` with the following SQL statement:

```
select 
    question_asked, cast(Response as integer) 
from 
    main_table 
where 
    question_asked = 'What is your age'
```

If I run a simple SQL query the results return as expected. But in some circumstances like when using a sum/group by query. I get an error msg (actual msg I get):

> *Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2011-08-13 00:00:00' to data type int*

In the table, `main_table`, one of the questions is the `start_date`, so the column `Response` does hold date values in the table, but not in the view I created.

Again, I can run a select query and check all the values for my `cast(Response as integer)` and they all are integer values.

My main question is: can anyone tell me if this is known/expected behavior in SQL Server 2008 R2, and/or does anyone else have another way to get a subset of values from this type of table other than creating a view?

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show a query where you have the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Alas, filtering by `isnumeric` doesn't necessarily work.  SQL is a descriptive language, not a procedural language.  So, the operations do not necessary work in the order specified.

In this case, SQL Server will attempt to do the conversion when reading the data *and then* apply the filter.  Too late.  You have an error.

The `case` statement is the only statement that guarantees order of evaluation, at least when aggregation functions are not involved.  The following should fix the conversion problem:

```
select question_asked,
       (case when isnumeric(Response) = 1 and
                  Response not like '%.%'
             then cast(Response as int)
        end) as Response
from main_table
where question_asked = 'What is your age'
```

This version also checks for a decimal point in Response.  `ISNUMERIC` will return 1 when there is a decimal point, but that will fail the conversion as well.

Answer (score 1):

Given the bug that [Martin has highlighted](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors), I would actually use the original condition in the CASE statement, which will apply to any numeric type, not limited to Gordon's int interpretation.  Better than ISNUMERIC, but TRY_CONVERT would be better from SQL Server 2012 onwards.  You would hope SQL Server can re-use the condition resolution in the WHERE clause to assist in the SELECT, or vice-versa.

```
select 
    question_asked, case when question_asked = 'What is your age'
                         then cast(Response as integer)
                         end
from 
    main_table 
where 
    question_asked = 'What is your age'
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter using `ISNUMERIC` - there may be non-integral data as responses which are messing up the aggregate functions.

```
SELECT
 question_asked,
 CASE(response AS INT)
FROM
 main_table
WHERE
 question_asked = 'What is your age'
 AND ISNUMERIC(response) = 1
```

Edit: if that still doesn't work, you may need to do some more aggressive type-checking on your `response` column. Check out the responses here:

[How to get if a string is a number in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109574/how-to-get-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-t-sql)

Comment: You are assuming the `WHERE` will happen before the cast as int. [This isn't guaranteed](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)

Comment: Wow - how about that... I've never actually run into that problem in the wild before. I guess the only foolproof method would be a subselect/CTE that pulls out rows with numeric `response`s, then feeds a final select statement.

Comment: The workaround is to use `CAST(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(response) = 1 THEN response END AS INT)`. Or if SQL Server 2012 use `TRY_CONVERT(int, response)`

Comment: @Martin I added an answer.  I prefer to stay far away from ISNUMERIC